# A question about $\det(A^TA)$

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m\leq n$. The aim is to find a lower and an upper bound for $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$. What can be said about this issue?

Comment: Note that $M = A^T A$ is a square matrix. Useful terminology you will see in the field is that $M$ is "positive semidefinite." There are lots of bounds for such matrices in terms of quantities associated with $M$ (and hence, if sometimes only indirectly, but often very directly, with $A$); https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality contains one example. There are many others; it depends on what data about $A$ you have or care about, and what you want to use your inequalities to conclude.

Comment: @ leslie townes, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

PS: I think the singular value decomposition of $A$ can help us to find an answer to this question. In fact, let us assume that $A=U\Sigma V^T$ in which $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are orthonormal matrices, i.e., $U^TU=I_m$ and $V^TV=I_n$. Moreover, the matrix $\Sigma$ is defined as
$$\Sigma=diag(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_r,0,\ldots,0)_{m\times n}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad \sigma_1\geq\sigma_2\geq\cdots\geq\sigma_r,$$
in which $\sigma_1$ is the largest singular value of $A$. Following this discussion, we have
$$\mathrm{det}(A^TA)=\mathrm{det}(V\Sigma^TU^TU\Sigma V^T)=\mathrm{det}(V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T)=\mathrm{det}(\Sigma^T\Sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^r \sigma_i^2\leq\sigma_1^{2r}.$$
On the other hand, since $0\leq\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$, we can say that
$$0\leq\mathrm{det}(A^TA)\leq \sigma_1^{2r}.$$

For this reason, $0$ and $\sigma_1^{2r}$ can be considered respectively as a lower bound and an upper bound for $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$. Is it possible to find other upper bounds for $\mathrm{det}(A^TA)$?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the other answer, $\det(A^TA)=\sigma^2_1\cdots\sigma^2_n$.

Using the GM-AM inequality $$\det{A^TA}=\sigma^2_1\cdots\sigma^2_n\le\left(\frac{\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2}{n}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{\|A\|^2_2}{n}\right)^{n}=\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{ij}a_{ij}^2\right)^{n}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. A piece of your answer is wrong. In fact, if $m\neq n$, the matrix $A^TA$ is not necessarily singular.

Comment: Thank you, if $m>n$ and the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $A^TA$ is symmetric positive definite (non-singular).

Comment: @Math-Data Ahh. I meant $n>m$. If there are more columns than rows, then they must be linearly dependent.